# Django Form Submission button not working

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

So, I am following code4startup tutorial on how to create a similar to Ubereats app. Right now, I am trying to register a new Restaurant & restaurant owner to the database. I am using a form from Django to handle all the datafields.

Everything works fine until I hit the "sign-up" button. My code is **SUPPOSED TO** POST all the data from the form into the database, then **automatically log-in** the newly created restaurant owner into the restaurants page. HOWEVER, when i press the sign-up button, nothing happens and instead the sign-up page is reloaded.

How can i solve this issue? The tutorial I'm following is from 2017 i think so the django version the author uses is old.

Below are some snippets from my code:

SIGN-UP HTML (BUTTON ONLY, FORM WORKS OK):

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ user_form }}
   {{ restaurant_form }}
<button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
```

VIEWS.py

```
def restaurant_home(request):
    return render(request, 'restaurant/home.html', {})

def restaurant_sign_up(request):
    user_form = UserForm()
    restaurant_form = RestaurantForm()

    #when submitting data:
    if request == "POST":
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
        restaurant_form = RestaurantForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if user_form.is_valid() and restaurant_form.is_valid():

            new_user = User.objects.create_user(**user_form.cleaned_data)
            new_restaurant = restaurant_form.save(commit=False)
            new_restaurant.user = new_user
            new_restaurant.save()

            login(request, authenticate(
                username = user.form.cleaned_data["username"],
                password = user.form.cleaned_data["password"]

            ))

            return redirect(restaurant_home)


    return render(request, 'restaurant/sign_up.html', {
        "user_form": user_form,
        "restaurant_form": restaurant_form

    })
```

Comment: normally it sends form to the same url - if you want to send form to different url then you have to use `<form action="differrent url" ...>`

Comment: simply use `print()` to see what you get in variables and which part of code is executed. ie. `print( request == "POST" )`

Comment: shouldn't be `request.method` in `if request.method == "POST":` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should be `request.method` in

```
if request.method == "POST":
```

---

Doc: [HttpRequest.method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.method)

Answer (score 0):

add the action attribute in the form tag to direct to the desired page

```
<form action=“/home“ method=“POST” ...>
```

Comment: Also tried that. The problem is the user the data from my form is never saved (restaurant and restaurant owner are never saved).